# Anaconda pre installed pip packages in new env

Tags: python, anaconda, environment-variables, conda

every time when I create a new conda env, I have pre-installed pip packages which I have installed in other env with the same python version. Is this right? I want to create a new env just with the necessary pip packages for a clean env.

I create a new env with:

```
conda create --name newenv python=3.8
```

Thats the same env on the picture, i tryed to uninstall and reinstall Anaconda navigator but the problem is still there.

Comment: don't think so, conda envs have a lot of preinstalled packages. are you sure that the packages you are looking for aren't preinstalled?

Comment: yes I'm sure packages like pycaret  arent preinstalled

Comment: Normally, packages from other environments shouldn't be picked up, especially by `conda list`, but environment variables (`PATH`, `PYTHONPATH`, etc.) can "leak" other Python installations when they have identical major.minor versions (3.8 only leaks to 3.8). The left Anaconda Navigator appears correct; the right looks like either not the env you are interested in, or leaking. Do you get the same result with `conda list -n newenv`?

Comment: Also, for the Pip-installed packages, any chance you used the `--user` flag? That is [explicitly recommended against in the docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#using-pip-in-an-environment). If so, you may need to delete (or at least remove from `PATH`) such a user-level cache of packages. Not sure where those are in Windows.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 2):

Every time a conda env is created one can specify default packages, by adding `create_default_packages` on the `.condarc` file.

If you want to ignore these default packages and for example install only some desired packages

```
conda create --no-default-packages -n myenv python=3.8 pycaret pandas scipy
```

or if you want these packages as default every time you create an environment add

```
create_default_packages:
  - pip
  - pycaret
  - pandas
  - scipy
```

to your `.condarc` file.

A third option is to pass package requirements through an `environment.yml` file through the `--f` argument. From the [docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#create-env-file-manually)

```
name: myenv
dependencies:
  - python=3.8   
  - pip
  - pycaret
  - pandas
  - scipy
```

Comment: There are no create_default_packages in my .condarc, i tryed the example in the docs

Comment: @PascalBlansche apologies, yes by default is not specified, one sets them manually. What is your ouput when specifying an `environment.yml` file?